# Count occurrences in Access query

Tags: ms-access

I am looking to see if its possible to run a count in an Access Query.

I have a list of data under `TeamName`

```
TeamName
----------
Liverpool
Liverpool
Liverpool
Liverpool
Liverpool
Manchester
Manchester
Newcastle
Newcastle
Stoke
Stoke
Stoke
```

I would you like a formula in Access that counts the number of occurrences in chronological order, so like below

```
TeamName    Count
--------    -----
Liverpool     1
Liverpool     2
Liverpool     3
Liverpool     4
Liverpool     5
Manchester    1
Manchester    2
Newcastle     1
Newcastle     2
Stoke         1
Stoke         2
Stoke         3
```

I've added a screenshot to see if that helps[image]

Comment: I can't see anything chronological in your sample data, does your table have additional columns?

Comment: Hi, There isn't anything chronological in my data. That's what I am trying to add. My table has the TeamName column only

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have any column that can be used to order the team names with the same name you have to first add such a column:

```
ALTER Table YourTable ADD TeamID AUTOINCREMENT(1,1);
```

now your table has a numeric id that you can use in a query to rank items with the same name like so:

```
select 
    teamname, 
    (select count(*) 
     from yourtable as t2 
    where t1.teamid > t2.teamid 
      and t1.teamname = t2.teamname
    ) + 1 as rank 
from yourtable t1;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.I do have a autonumber ID in the table already. I am pulling the data in a query. Below is the code I have changed but I am receiving an error 
    select 
    Team, 
    (select count(*) 
     from QryBranchSecPlayerRegRawData as t2 
    where t1.ID > t2.ID 
      and t1.Team = t2.Team
    ) + 1 as rank 
from QryBranchSecPlayerRegRawData t1;

Sorry I can't get the code thing to work

Comment: @padders01 The query looks correct. Do you get any error when executing it?

Comment: Hi, yes I get "invalid argument to function"

Comment: @padders01 Do you still have the `alter table` query too in the query window? You only want the select query and it shouldn't give that error.

Comment: No, just the select query. Haven't used the alter table already have TeamID autonumber in the table

Comment: I've added a photo of the data the query produces

ID and Team

Comment: @padders01 Then I don't know what might be the issue. I can run the query in your comment without any issues (using Access 2010).  In your picture the ID does not increment, which would mean it is not an autonumber column (if it were there wouldn't be any duplicates).

Comment: The ID in the table is a AutoNumber, the query is bringing duplicates (I want it to) due to the link of other data

Comment: You need to include `PRIMARY KEY` in the `ALTER TABLE` in order to make the `TeamID` autonumber column behave as intended.

Comment: @padders01 First you stated that TeamName was the only column, then that you actually have an autonumber ID, and now that the query is linked to other tables. We cannot make any guesses about your actual setup, so please update the question so it accurately tells the whole story.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that you needed to know what other information the query is pulling. I am looking to count the number of occurrences a team names appears but in chronological order.